# How get information from laravel controller in typescript

Tags: ajax, laravel, typescript

I have a problems sending information from a Laravel controller to TypeScript (TS) 
I have tried using Ajax but I have not been able to get the information sent from controller

**Laravel controller**

```
public function getUrl()
{
    $Id       = request('id');
    $urlAdjunto = Adjunto::where('articulo_id', $Id)->plunk('url');
    return response()->json(['url' => $urlAdjunto]);
}
```

**Ajax function in typescript**

```
function getUrl(id) {
    var a=  $.ajax({
        type    : 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url     : '/adjunto',
        data    : {id}
    });
    return a;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use `.then` or `.success` in typescript ? if yes then use it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i try to get a value from bbdd

Answer (score 0):

A few small modifications to make this type safe and return a promise as expected:

```
async function getUrl(id: number): Promise<any> {
   return await $.ajax({
       type: 'get',
       dataType: 'json',
       url: '/adjunto',
       data: {id}
   })
}
```

And now you have a promise to work with that you can observe and react to in your code:

```
getUrl(15)
   .then((response: any) => {
      //response.data has everything you need
   }).catch((error: any) => {
      // do something with failures
   })
```

Or call it from another `async` function and leverage `await` for cleaner syntax:

```
async myFunc(){
  try {
    const { data } = await getUrl(15)

    // do something with your data
  } catch(error) {
    // we all make mistakes
  }
}
```

Comment: Im afraid that solution is wrong on the sintaxis , however thank you por your answer